# Style not changing in Trent Richardson's datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have implemented Trent Richardson's datetimepicker in jQuery. I have a dropdown depending on which I have to change the style of Calendar and Clock to simple Calendar control and vice-versa, but the style is not changing.

Below is my code:

```
function changeCalander() {
    var val = $("#<%=ddlTripType.ClientID %>").val();
    var dtFormat;
    if ($("#<%=hfTimeZone.ClientID %>").val() == 'India Standard Time') {
        dtFormat = 'dd/mm/yy';
    }
    else {
        dtFormat = 'mm/dd/yy';
    }
    if (val == 0) {
        $('#<%=txtStartTime.ClientID %>').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: dtFormat,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
        $("#<%=txtEndTime.ClientID %>").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: dtFormat,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    }
    else if (val == 1) {
        $('#<%=txtStartTime.ClientID %>').datepicker({
            dateFormat: dtFormat,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
        $("#<%=txtEndTime.ClientID %>").datepicker({
            dateFormat: dtFormat,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that you get the correct value (`console.log( $("#<%=hfTimeZone.ClientID %>").val() )`) and that the function is being called when the value of dropdown changes?

Comment: yes that is correct. even the function is getting executed but there is no effect taking place.

Comment: anyone out there...please help